# Android Action Bar replace context menu icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

Hello i want to change **4** to an help icon **or** if this is not possible, hide it and add a help icon to **3**.
I dont want it to be a dropdown menu, i just want a clickable icon.
And is there a way to hide/show it from within a fragment?

I tried to change **res/menu/menu_main3.xml** but nothing happened.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.test.test.Main3Activity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_outline_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, you have to implement your custom `Toolbar`, which is just a `ViewGroup`. So you will be able to add and adjust any views (in this case it would be `ImageButton`)